# How to create this sequence using latex?

Tags: tikz-pgf, graphics, diagrams

I want to create my own image sequence that is like this

[image]

How can I create this exactly like it is with my own images?

Comment: As always on this website, please post a [MWE](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-working-example-mwe-what-is-that) of what you have tried so far and showing what point exactly you are struggling with. There are already a lot of answers on TeX.SX helping you to draw this kind of diagram.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can draw something like this with Ti*k*Z but only if you provide more information<sup>1</sup> one can be sure that you achieve what you want.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{chains}
\newsavebox\ClippedPicA
\newsavebox\ClippedPicB
\sbox\ClippedPicA{\begin{tikzpicture}
\node[outer sep=0pt,inner sep=0pt] (c) {\phantom{\includegraphics[width=3cm]{example-image-duck}}};
\clip ([xshift=2ex,yshift=2ex]c.south west) rectangle 
    ([xshift=-2ex,yshift=-2ex]c.north east);
\node (c) {\includegraphics[width=3cm]{example-image-duck}};    
\end{tikzpicture}}
\sbox\ClippedPicB{\begin{tikzpicture}
\node[outer sep=0pt,inner sep=0pt,scale=0.8] (c) {\phantom{\includegraphics[width=3cm]{example-image-duck}}};
\clip ([xshift=2ex,yshift=2ex]c.south west) rectangle 
    ([xshift=-2ex,yshift=-2ex]c.north east);
\node (c) {\includegraphics[width=3cm]{example-image-duck}};    
\end{tikzpicture}}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[arj/.style={-latex}] 
\begin{scope}[start chain=R going right,
    nodes={on chain,join=by arj}]
 \path node{\includegraphics[width=3cm]{example-image-duck}}
  node{\usebox\ClippedPicA}
  node[scale=0.8]{\usebox\ClippedPicA}
  node{\usebox\ClippedPicB}
  [arj/.append style={opacity=0}]
  node[opacity=0]{\usebox\ClippedPicB}
  node[opacity=0]{\usebox\ClippedPicB}
  [arj/.append style={opacity=1}]
  node{\usebox\ClippedPicB}
  node[opacity=0.5]{\usebox\ClippedPicB}
  ;
\end{scope} 
\path (R-5) node[matrix] {\node(R-5-1){\usebox\ClippedPicB};\\
   \node[rotate=90](R-5-2){\usebox\ClippedPicB};\\
   \node[rotate=180](R-5-3){\usebox\ClippedPicB};\\
   \node[rotate=270](R-5-4){\usebox\ClippedPicB};\\}
   (R-6) node[matrix] {\node[xscale=-1](R-6-1){\usebox\ClippedPicB};\\
   \node[yscale=-1](R-6-2){\usebox\ClippedPicB};\\};
\path[arj] (R-4.east) foreach \X in {1,...,4} { edge (R-5-\X.270-90*\X)}   
(R-5.east) foreach \X in {1,2} { edge (R-6-\X.180-180*\X)};   
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

<sub><sup>1</sup>To be clear, "more information" means to edit the question such that it shows what you have tried and give more details. It does not mean to ask for additional features in the comments.</sub>